# Capybara headless chrome doesn't support javascript content

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am using a headless chrome driver

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :headless_chrome
Capybara.default_driver = :headless_chrome
```

And it seems that content has not been loaded, I have also tried to use chrome and pause on debugger on a step.

```
Capybara.javascript_driver = :chrome
Capybara.default_driver = :chrome

Then(/^I should see my content$/) do
  byebug
end
```

I can now see the content has not been loaded on my chrome browser.

Comment: You're going to need to provide more info than that.  Test setup, versions you're using, etc.  I'm also not sure how you can see your content still hasn't been loaded when you're still using headless chrome.  Additionally put a `sleep 10` in front of your byebug call  just in case the way you way you built it is also pausing the apps thread and preventing the request from being served.

Comment: Ok - you've updated to show that you're now using Chrome rather than headless chrome -- so try putting the sleep in front of byebug and see if the content then loads.  Additionally if this is the first test being run it may be that your assets are taking a long time to compile.  You should be able to see that in your `test.log`, or try precompiling the assets for the test environment before running the test.